# I need customize ng-grid

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-grid

Hi I want to make a list of ng-grid,  angular.js, but with the format bootstrap table , someone has gotten ? Or create a table with data from ng -grid and his functionality

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You will find very good example for ng-grid.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: Please provide some context for this link (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Recently `ng-grid` has been migrated to [`ui-grid`](http://ui-grid.info/) and they provided better UI control & user interface,

Rather than go for own customization take a look at `ui-grid` own [customization of header](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/302_custom_header), [customization of row template](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/301_custom_row_template) & [customization of column menu](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/303_customizing_column_menu)

**Note**

> Angular `ui-grid` still in beta stage, its not a stable version.

Hope this could help you. Thanks.